# how to change obejcts in List of class of objects?

Tags: c#

you are power that can help me to understand objects and classes.

I have list with all orders (name, price and quantity). So now I should check if some item is two or more time at list, I should add quantity and update price with last recieved 
 Example : Beer 2.40 350 Water 1.25 200 IceTea 5.20 100 Beer 1.20 200 IceTea 0.50 120 Buy Answer is:Beer -> 660.00 Water -> 250.00 IceTea -> 110.00

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();

            while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "Buy")
                { break; }
                    string[] tokens = input.Split();
                    string product = tokens[0];
                    decimal price = decimal.Parse(tokens[1]);
                    int quantity = int.Parse(tokens[2]);
                Orders order = new Orders(product, price, quantity);
                orders.Add(order);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, orders));
        }
    }

    class Orders
    {
        public Orders(string name,decimal price,int quantity)
        {
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
            Quantity = quantity;

        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            decimal finalPrice = Price * Quantity;
            return $"{Name} -> {finalPrice}";
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with your code?

Comment: I have list with all input data - Orders order = new Orders(product, price, quantity);
                orders.Add(order)- but i dont know how to menage with list items. So if You have follow input : Beer 2.40 350
Water 1.25 200
IceTea 5.20 100
Beer 1.20 200
IceTea 0.50 120
Buy
 
Answer is:Beer -> 660.00
Water -> 250.00
IceTea -> 110.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();

        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "Buy") break;
            string[] tokens = input.Split();
            string product = tokens[0];
            decimal price = decimal.Parse(tokens[1]);
            int quantity = int.Parse(tokens[2]);
            Orders order = orders.Find(a => a.Name == product);
            if (order == null)
            {
                order = new Orders(product, price, quantity);
                orders.Add(order);
            }
            else
            {
                order.Price = price;
                order.Quantity += quantity;
            }
        }

        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{order.Name} :-> {(order.Price * order.Quantity)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is same output. I need to know if I have two waters how to add quantity and change price on list?

Comment: Now, I understand your problem. I updated the code.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you! Now, I understand too. 